# Finding Dynamic text value of static field using mechanize browser python

Tags: python, dynamic, mechanize

How can I find the Dynamic text that is as per the user details entered of the static field result using mechanize browser in python.
 I can do it using "split" function as splitting the text and storing the text in a variable. But is there any function that will directly give me results as:
Name: abc
Addr: pqr
Gender: male

```
abc=mechanize.Browser()
abc.set_handle_robots(False)
abc.open(url)
abc._factory.is_html = True
abc.select_form(nr=0)
x=abc.submit()
m=x.read()
```

I tried using 'findAll' but not working well. Here abc can be any name as per the login. Data are not of any text box input values.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this should tell you the field names:

```
for f in br.forms()
print f.name
```

fill in the blanks:

```
form["field1"] = ["input1"]
```

hope this is what you were asking for. cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Onur, but as specified, the data in the form are not from any input fields.
It is as, after you login to your Telephone Bill site, it displays current month bill details as,
Local: xx
ISD:    xx
Tax:    xx
Grand Total: xx